# How to use a customized Forward-To-a Friend (FTAF) Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

We have a custom landing page and wanted to use to it for the Forward-To-a Friend (FTAF) functionality rather than using the default FTAF Page. How can it be achieved? We like to keep all the FTAF Tracking functionality on the custom landing page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For those of us who don't know what FTAF is without Googling, I assume it is [Forward to a Friend](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/forward_to_a_friend/).